# How to Calculate SqrtPriceX96 for a Specific Percentage Change in Uniswap v3?

Tags: uniswap, defi, uniswapv3, sqrtpricelimitx96

I am working with Uniswap v3 and need to calculate the `sqrtPriceX96` value that is exactly 5% (or any other percentage) above or below the current pool price. I understand that each tick in Uniswap v3 represents a price movement of approximately 1 basis point. Could I use this understanding to calculate the `sqrtPriceX96` for a price that is a certain percentage above or below the current price by simply moving a corresponding number of ticks? What are the potential accuracy or resolution trade-offs with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

To calculate a `sqrtPriceX96` that is a specific percentage (e.g., 5%) above or below the current pool price in Uniswap v3, you can indeed use the tick-based approach. Each tick in Uniswap v3 roughly corresponds to a 1 basis point change in price. To adjust the price by, say, 5%, which is 500 basis points, you can add or subtract 500 ticks from the current tick to get the approximate `sqrtPriceX96` that is 5% from the current price.

Here's a general approach in Solidity:

```
import { TickMath } from '@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/libraries/TickMath.sol';

function calculateAdjustedSqrtPriceX96(uint160 currentSqrtPriceX96, int24 basisPointsDelta)
    external
    pure
    returns (uint160 adjustedSqrtPriceX96)
{
    int24 currentTick = TickMath.getTickAtSqrtRatio(currentSqrtPriceX96);
    int24 adjustedTick = currentTick + basisPointsDelta;
    adjustedSqrtPriceX96 = TickMath.getSqrtRatioAtTick(adjustedTick);
}
```

**Accuracy and Resolution Trade-offs:**

1. **Precise Tick Calculation with Logarithms**: The use of logarithmic calculations for determining the number of ticks corresponding to a specific percentage change is more precise. Since price movements in ticks follow a geometric progression, logarithms accurately capture the necessary tick adjustments. So in the 5% price delta example, the actual number of ticks is 488 and not 500. See [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/138118/86303) for more detail.
2. **Challenges with Solidity Computations**: Implementing logarithmic calculations in Solidity can be complex and gas-intensive. Solidity’s lack of native support for floating-point arithmetic and advanced math functions like logarithms makes on-chain calculations of this nature less straightforward.
3. **Quantization in Tick Spacing**: While the logarithmic approach is mathematically precise, the fixed tick intervals in Uniswap v3 still introduce a quantization effect. This effect can result in small deviations, especially when dealing with very fine price movements for e.g. within 1 bsp(0.01%).
4. **Precomputed Lookup Tables for Efficiency**: To balance precision and computational efficiency, using precomputed lookup tables for common percentage changes is a practical solution. This approach avoids complex on-chain calculations by referencing off-chain computed values.